# Awk: make an average in file with both number and string

Tags: regex, awk

here is my problem (not sure that my title was clear), I have to display an average of number in a file. However there is string in the file too.

```
file: test
```

`Richie;jack;27 Yo;07Richiej@gmail.com  
Cash;tom;29 Yo;Ctom01@gmail.com  
Megane;susan;37 Yo;meganeSusan@gmail.com`

...

it has to display the average age of the people in my file, I'm not supposed to know how many people there are.

I thought about using RegEx to only get number in my 3rd field, but got errors each time.
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"} /      /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the average of the number in the third column:

```
$ awk -F\; '{s+=$3} END{print s/NR}' test
31
```

#### How it works

- `-F\;`

  This tells awk to use `;` as the field separator.  Because `;` is a shell-active character, we have to either escape it (as shown above) or quote it.
- `s+=$3`

  For each line read, this adds the number in the third column to `s`.  Because `+=` is an arithmetic operation, awk converts the third field to a number.

  This code also illustrates awk's automatic conversion of fields to numbers:

  ```
  $ awk -F\; '{printf "field=\"%s\" number=%s\n", $3, $3+0}' test
  field="27 Yo" number=27
  field="29 Yo" number=29
  field="37 Yo" number=37
  ```

  When we print `$3`, we get the full string including the `Yo`.  When we print `$3+0`, the conversion to a number is forced and, as shown above, we just get the number.
- `END{print s/NR}`

  After we have reached the end of the file, this prints the total of the third columns, save in `s`, divided by the number of lines read, `NR`.

Comment: Wow, never thought it'll work like this !
I supposed that it ignore not number element in the $3.

Comment: nitpick - that'll produce a division by zero error when run on an empty file. You should really use `print (NR ? s/NR : 0)` or similar to protect against that. Also `number=%s...$3+0` can be written as just `number=%d...$3`

Comment: @EdMorton Good points.  On the other hand, the division by zero causes awk to return a non-zero exit code which might, depending on how the code is used, be the appropriate response to an empty input file.